# Function to shorten string without cutting off last word

Tags: excerpt

This code is working great to shorten a strong of text to the nearest end of a word except that if the string is shorter than the cut length, it cuts off the last word. Can anyone tell me what to change to make it not cut off the last word in that instance?

```
function shortened_description($cutlength) {
    $content   = get_field('event_short_description');
    $charcount = strlen($content);
    $cutlength = $cutlength;
    $shorter   = substr($content, 0, strrpos(substr($content, 0, $cutlength), ' '));
    if ($charcount >= $cutlength) {
        echo $shorter . '... <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">more ></a>';
    } //$charcount >= $cutlength
    else {
        echo $shorter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to achieve this as listed following.

Using [wordwrap()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) function :

```
function shortened_description($cutlength) {
    $content   = get_field('event_short_description');
    $charcount = strlen($content);
    $content = wordwrap($content, 28);
    $content = explode("\n", $content);
    $shorter = $content[0];

    if ($charcount >= $cutlength) {
        echo $shorter . '... <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">more ></a>';
    } //$charcount >= $cutlength
    else {
        echo $shorter;
    }

}
```

Using [preg_match(](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)) function :

```
function shortened_description($cutlength) {
    $content   = get_field('event_short_description');
    $charcount = strlen($content);

    if ($charcount >= $cutlength) {
    preg_match("/^.{1,$cutlength}\b/s", $content, $match);
        echo $match[0] . '... <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">more ></a>';
    } //$charcount >= $cutlength
    else {
        echo $content;
    }

}
```

Using [wp_trim_words()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words) function :

( Note it will trim strings based on number of words passed as a parameter )

```
function shortened_description($cutlength) {
    $content   = get_field('event_short_description');
    $shorter = wp_trim_words($content, $cutlength, '... <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">more ></a>');
    echo $shorter;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is that this works unless the string is SHORTER than the specified cutlength. If it is shorter, it cuts off the last word. I tried your example and it seems to do the same thing unfortunately.

Comment: @Eckstein Which example have you tried?

Comment: I tried both. The top one (larger one) cuts off the last word. The bottom one displays the "...more >" even if the string is shorter, which I also don't want.

Comment: I just refreshed the page and saw your updated answer. The middle one worked! The preg_match() one. Thank you for your thorough examples.

Comment: I tested all the examples and it's working correctly. can you just try using some dummy text like $content = "Lorem ipsum sdf xdvkbgd"; instead of  $content   = get_field('event_short_description');